# Installing Qt on Linux (Debian distribution)

Tags: linux, qt

I have Qt  4.6.3 on Debian. I need version 4.8.1.

To install it I downloaded the **Qt SDK 1.2.1** from the Qt site, where is said that it contains version 4.8.1
After installation I checked Qt version and it is 4.6.3 instead of expected 4.8.1.

What I am doing wrong? And how can I install 4.8.1?

Comment: How did you check the Qt version, did you just look again in the Debian package manager?

Comment: Did you uninstall the old version and put the new SDK into your `PATH`? Otherwise typing the above into the command line will call `qmake` 4.6.3.

Comment: No I didn`t. Could you please write how to uninstall old version and put SDK in the path?

Comment: Note that the Qt SDK will be installed in a "local folder", not into your system. Thus it will not show up in `$PATH` unless you add the Qt SDK installation path to `$PATH`. As a result, `qmake` will per default point to the installed version from your package manager. One solution to allow multiple installations (package + one or more "local installations") is to use `update-alternatives` as shown in this blog post: http://jpnurmi.kapsi.fi/blog/2008/03/16/how-to-switch-qt-version-in-ubuntu/ (it's for Ubuntu but should apply to Debian too).

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It works perfectly in Debian also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I recommend getting 'official' Debian Qt upgrades by adding the testing (wheezy) repo to your package manager, this way everything on your system will be updated seamlessly in a few clicks.

If you can't do this, then:

- Use your package manager to uninstall the existing Qt installation (so that's the runtime libs, plugins, and Qt Creator).
- Install the SDK anywhere you like, it installs under one folder anyway.
- Update your `$PATH` to point to the directory with `qtcreator`, `qmake`, etc., there are numerous ways of doing this, the simplest is exporting the updated `$PATH` in your `.bashrc`. (And optionally make some nice shortcuts for your DE).
- Create symlinks in `/usr/lib` (or `/usr/lib64`) to point to the Qt libraries the SDK provides, or add a `qt.conf` file containing the path in your `/etc/ld.conf.so.d/` directory and run `ldconfig` as root.

I'm an openSUSE user myself, so some of the above may slightly different on Debian, hopefully someone with Debian experience can chime in if I'm incorrect.

Comment: Yeah using package manager is a good idea instead of trying to manually install, especially since the author does not seem familiar with Linux. Debian testing should be reasonably stable.

Comment: @cmannett85. Thank you very much. I went on first way and set repository wheezy instead of sqeeze. I updated Qt packages and now I got needed version of Qt. But where were some disadvantages: as I run Debian on VirtualBox I had to reinstall guest additions, I have already done this and all went fine. I didn`t choose 2-nd variant which you advised due to I need to find all Qt files manualy to select them for uninstallation which is very time consuming operation.

Comment: I already asked my question few times but nobody wasn`t able to answer it. Original version: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49281/trying-to-use-multiple-debian-repositories